# mouseDown issue on custom view for a menubar app

Tags: objective-c, click, menubar

i'm trying to code a drag&drop menubar app. i used a custom view to access to the dropped file, and this works fine. now i would like to open the default menu when clicking on this view. i'm using this:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
   [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:statusMenu];
}
```

now, the **mouseDown** works fine (trying with NSLog), but still i cannot access to *statusItem* and *statusMenu*.

this is in *dropView.m*, in *dropView.h* i got:

```
@interface dropView : NSView{
    IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
    NSStatusItem *statusItem;
}
```

no crash, no logs… any ideas? ty!

this is a bit more from the .m

```
- (void)awakeFromNib{
    statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu];
    dropView *drop = [[dropView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 24, 24)];
    [statusItem setView:drop];
}
```

Comment: nope this give and error (property not found)

Comment: Did you synthesize the properties?

Comment: **2012-07-24 16:50:54.107 CopyDrop[13783:403] -[dropView statusMenu]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd6eb821760**

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSMenu *statusMenu;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusItem;
```

Add this to your .m file:

```
@synthesize statusMenu, statusItem;
```

Then you'll access the properties with `self.statusMenu` and `self.statusItem`.

Comment: 2012-07-24 17:15:27.482 CopyDrop[14728:403] statusMenu: (null)
statusItem: (null)

Comment: So you're accessing them, they just don't have anything in them. I assumed that you were setting them to something...

Comment: shouldn't you be using self.statusItem and self.statusMenu?

Comment: i do:
**- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:self.statusMenu];
}**

Comment: You aren't in your `awakeFromNib` method